# SDK Manager устарел?

Tags: android

Я не могу скачать в SDK Manager'e библиотеки *ConstraintLayout for Android* и *Solver for ConstraintLayout*, потому что этих пунктов в SDK Manager вообще нет. 
Вот как выглядит окно SDK Manager'a:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя, насколько я понимаю, библиотеки *ConstraintLayout for Android* и *Solver for ConstraintLayout* должны быть вложены в папку *Support Repository*, которая должна быть вместо папки *Extras*.
Может ли это быть из-за того, что SDK Manager устарел? И можно ли его обновить, не обновляя остальное sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости SDK Manager действительно остался в прошлом, в официальной документации упоминания о этой утилите в графическом интерфейсе исключены, осталась только [консольная утилита](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) для тех несчастных, кто до сих пор не перешел на Android Studio, в [разделе по обновлению компонентов Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager) прямо так и сказано.
Кроме того, после последнего стабильного обновления (AS 2.3) лично у меня вообще не запускаются утилиты AVD Manager.exe и SDK Manager.exe из пакета Android SDK, который устанавливался с самой студией. Для счастливых же обладателей студии предлагается пользоваться SDK Manager-ом самой студии (как и AVD Manager): Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager (кстати раньше этот пункт запускал SDK Manager из пакета Android SDK, теперь мэнеджер студии)

Если вам нужно использовать в проекте именно `ConstraintLayout` и использовать SDK Manager студии вы не можете, то вы можете либо указать зависимость в build.gradle проекта напрямую:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

и тогда, если в локальном репозитории еще нет этой библиотеки, вы получите предупреждение Gradle следующего вида:

[image: screen]

Необходимо выбрать *Install artefact and sync project*, данная библиотека подключится и ее можно будет использовать в проекте.

Так же вы можете просто добавить `ConstrainLayout` на разметку в режиме визуального редактора:

[image: screen2]

И тогда вы получите сообщение, либо как на этом скрине, в случае, если сам пакет уже установлен в локальный репозиторий, но зависимость в проекте не указана. Либо предупреждение Gradle, аналогичное первому скрину, если в локальном репозитории этой библиотеки нет. Дейсвтовать нужно аналогично первому варианту.

После этих простых манипуляций библиотеку можно использовать в своем проекте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То есть, как я поняла (по этому ответу и комментарию к вопросу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641825/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-android-studio-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-sdk-tools), мне нужно переустановить AS и при установке  выбрать опцию "скачать android-sdk вместе со студией", а не указывать путь к уже имеющемуся на диске android-sdk, как я делала раньше?)

Comment: @Ksenia вы можете скачать [полный пакет разработчика Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (размер 1.8Гб) . Туда входит все необходимое (студия, SDK, JDK и пр.) и уже настроено. Лучше не переустановить, а удалить старую и все с ней связанное, включая в папке пользователя служебные файлы, а потом начисто установить.