# AVD из папки больше не работает , так же как и SDK manager. Нужны вирт.устройска,которые были в ADV manager.exe

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор, avd

Недавно была проблема, Avd при запуске из студии выдавал телефоны с нестандартными dpi, плотности 2,625 или 2,5. 420 dpi на FullHd при 5,5 дюймах. А запустив из папки SDK AVD Manager.exe  получал другие девайся с нормальными параметрами. Решил обновиться и теперь больше из папки AVD Manager.exe не запускается. и Перестал запускать SDK . В андроид студио кнопка в разделе SDK ,которая запускала SDK из папки перестала реагировать. После обновления студии кнопка и вовсе пропала.  Прочитав ответ на этот вопрос [SDK Manager устарел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642170/)  понял, что эти утилиты из папки больше не поддерживаются. Так где мне теперь взять виртуальные устройства с нормальными параметрами экрана, которые были в ADV manager.  Вот что есть у меня https://gyazo.com/82ff701a341d783d166fd79eeb9a4500

Comment: Вы можете нажать New Hardware Profile и создать  устройство с любыми параметрами - в том числе размер экрана и количество его пикселей. Вообще странно, что эмулятор из SDK и эмулятор Android Studio создают разные устройства при одинаковых параметрах этих устройств. Я такого не замечал.

Comment: У них вообще разные интерфейсы даже.. New Hardware Profile не дает возможности изменить плотность.  Можно менять только разрешение и диагональ, а плотность он сам меняет, но совсем не правильно. Ставит плотность, которая не рекомендуется для такого экрана. А вот из SDK эмулятор имел   другие профили, но после обновления его не стало.

Comment: pavlofff, приложите пожалуйста скрин вашего AVD на вкладке Create new device

Comment: Там все так же, как и у всех. Что бы вы хотели увидеть на таком скриншоте? Вообще, ваши последние вопросы несколько "странные", за ~5 лет мне ни разу не приходилось задумываться о плотностях эмуляторов, различия их создания разными программами, как и проблемах уменьшения изображений при загрузке в Bitmap и прочее с этим связанное - все просто работает и дает ожидаемые результаты. Складывается впечатление, что вы что то делаете не так и проблемы ваших вопросов где то глубже

Comment: Ну не знаю,  одно дело когда из-за кнопок Домой Назад вместо 1920 получаю 1776, а другое когда на fullhd экране плотность 2,625 и в папкк xxhdpi приходится файлы заливать больше чем 1920 на 1080

Comment: И еще заметил, что какие ты я эмуляции не создавал в игрушке которую я писал fps не более 20..хотя раньше 100 легко выдавало.  Решил что я нагрузил игрушку и отключил вообще прорисовку и всякие расчеты,  только сухой подсчет fps и результат достиг 25.. Что то тут не так..